# What does the "size" of a symlink represent in ls output?

Tags: symbolic-link, ls

I'll start by example:

```
$ ls -l dir1
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 4 maythux maythux 1650 2008-01-10 16:33 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 maythux maythux  7 2008-01-15 15:17 symfile -> file
```

`symfile` is a symlink of the file `file`

Also as i know `1650` would be the size of the file `file`, but what is the number `7` that is laid under the size column?

EDIT:
Running `du`:

```
$ du -sh symfile
0   symfile
```

So how could you prove that 7 is the symlink size?!

---

UPDATE:

try this

```
$ touch file
$ du -sh file
0 file
$ ls -l file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 maythux maythux 0 Jun  1 19:42 file
```

note that size is also here 0.

Now:

```
$ ln -s file sym
$ du -sh sym
0 sym
$ ls -l sym
lrwxrwxrwx 1 maythux maythux 4 Jun  1 19:44 sym -> file
```

So, I suppose it's not only a size

Comment: The `7` depends on the filesystem (and possibly other parameters). It's 7 on ext4, but could be 13 on btrfs and 3 on tmpfs.

Comment: Then it's not really just a size?

Comment: It is a size, but the size depends on the filesystem (btrfs presumably stores more metadata than ext4, and ext4 more than tmpfs). You can fill your disk with links. I'm just saying, don't be surprised if you see a different number on a different filesystem.

Comment: [Do symbolic links actually make a difference in disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/do-symbolic-links-actually-make-a-difference-in-disk-usage)

Comment: @muru I understand that, but try this create a symlink for empty file, then `du -sh symlink` gives 0 while in `ls -l` is not like, it has some value, I think there is something else than size

Comment: Your directory entry has a minimum size to it, larger than it needs. Make enough entries and the size of the *directory* will increase. Check with: `mkdir foo; ls -ld foo; for i in {1..1000}; do ln -s foo/bar foo/$i; done; ls -ld foo`.

Comment: @Maythux Ill counter the downvote :D

Comment: @Rinzwind I really dont care for repuatation itself, I care for why

Comment: Also: [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55/70524)

Comment: @muru Thanks for useful links, you are a teacher

Comment: Did you read [this](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Symbolic_Links)? I've posted a [releated answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626634/convert-a-file-to-directory/626731#626731).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Symbolic links take the room it takes to store the name and target plus a few bytes for other metadata.

So it is the size of the symlink.

Regarding the size from `du -sh`: `du`  only looks at how many blocks are allocated, and so may show 0.`stat` and `ls -l` are better in showing the size in that regard.

Comment: then why `du -sh symfile` gives 0? –

Comment: du only looks at how many blocks are allocated, and so may show 0. stat and ls -l are smarter.

Comment: Please read the update

Comment: See my answer: it is the name, target and some metadata.  In total it makes up for 7 bytes. Other OS store other metadata and so will have a different size.

Comment: The question was "How can you PROVE IT?"

Comment: Aha then there is something other than size itself, though varies

Comment: @Pilot6 he suggests to use `stat` and yes it works proving some more information about a file. It still varies from one FS to other, I use some other distros shows different size

Answer (score 5):

It is the size of the symlink in bytes.

Some file systems have a small area inside the directory entry that is used for the beginning of the file, which significantly speeds up processing of symlinks and small reads (think `file`) at the expense of larger directory entries.

If the entire symlink contents fit into the directory entry, then no data blocks are allocated, and the `du` size shows as zero. If the symlink doesn't fit, space is allocated normally (so you end up with a single block allocation), which may be optimized by the filesystem using tail merging (but there is no API for `du` to know about this).

The `ext4` filesystem performs this optimization for symlinks only, the criteria are found in the function [ext4_inode_is_fast_symlink](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/inode.c#L148).

Comment: "_Some file systems ..._" - your answer would be improved if you listed the common file systems with this feature (and any common ones without).

Answer (score 1):

This is size of the symlink file in bytes.

Symlink file is a normal file that stores data regarding where is the file it is pointing to. In ext 4 it is 7 bytes.

Comment: size in what? is it Bytes or bits or What?

Comment: Size in bytes..

Comment: then why `du -sh symfile` gives 0?

Comment: du is not presize with very small files. Try to use du at some 99 bytes file. It will show 4.0K.

Comment: that's my pioint also then it should at least show 4k for the symlink since in OS concept it's registring a cluster for this file