# What does the 's' in srwxr-xr-x in the 'ls' output mean?

Tags: permissions, files, directory, ls

I have a directory entry as follows

```
srwxr-xr-x  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 May 29 05:03 0.0.0.0=
```

I do not know what the `s` means and also that is a strange file name and I wonder what it is good for. Could this be garbage or is it something meaningful?

Comment: Remotely related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/626634/converting-a-file-to-directory/626731#626731 On the answer there is a script that explains and calculates the inode modes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [the `ls` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed):

> The file type is one of the following characters:
>
> ‘-’ regular file
>   ‘b’ block special file
>   ‘c’ character special file
>   ‘C’ high performance (“contiguous data”) file
>   ‘d’ directory
>   ‘D’ door (Solaris 2.5 and up)
>   ‘l’ symbolic link
>   ‘M’ off-line (“migrated”) file (Cray DMF)
>   ‘n’ network special file (HP-UX)
>   ‘p’ FIFO (named pipe)
>   ‘P’ port (Solaris 10 and up)
>   ‘s’ socket
>   ‘?’ some other file type

So, that's a [Unix socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). It could be meaningful, since sockets are created by processes to listen for requests. Use `lsof` to determine what process is using that socket.

You may need to use `sudo` with `lsof`, if the socket is opened by a process running as another user:

```
$ lsof /run/snapd.socket
$ sudo lsof /run/snapd.socket
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
systemd     1 root  197u  unix 0xffff99dc9afa3000      0t0 191670 /run/snapd.socket type=STREAM
snapd   18626 root    8u  unix 0xffff99dc9afa3000      0t0 191670 /run/snapd.socket type=STREAM
```

Comment: You can also use [`fuser`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) to determine the processes using a file.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `file` command to determine its type too:

```
$ file /tmp/ssh-k405k6mf0/agent.1221
/tmp/ssh-k405k6mf0/agent.1221: socket
```

or even `mimetype`:

```
$ mimetype /tmp/ssh-k405k6mf0/agent.1221
/tmp/ssh-k405k6mf0/agent.1221: inode/socket
```

Answer (score 1):

To add up, this file type is also called ***special file*** there are multiple special files exist in UNIX (all of them are listed as part of ls manual, useful snippet is provided by muru).

Further read - https://www.linux.com/blog/file-types-linuxunix-explained-detail

Comment: Your answer is not wrong.  To make it better, consider adding additional information to your answer - such as that it is a socket file. Links can provide extra information, but your answer should be able to stand on its own without the link and still provide a thorough response.